# Robot Framework: am I implementing the Page Object Pattern the right way?

Tags: automation, robotframework

I've read a few articles and examples but I'm still unsure about how to organize my test suites.

Let's say I'll be testing a company website, with a home page that has a menu taking the user to pages like "about", "products", "contact us".

This is what I've come up with so far to structure my project, but I'm not sure it's the best way in terms of scalability and maintainability:

`/src/test/robotframework/acceptance` contains a **GeneralResources.robot** file and **one folder per website page**.

- `GeneralResources.robot` file contains a "Settings" section with Library references that will be used by all tests (e.g.: Selenium2Library)
- `/home` folder contains 4 files:

  1. `__init__.robot` with *Test Setup* and *Test Teardown* for all the home page tests.
  2. `Resources.robot` with global variables (like *${home_url}* or *${home_title}*) and higher level keywords that the home page tests will use.
  3. `PageObjects.robot` with variables that store locators for all the objects that will be tested in the home page (e.g.: main logo, main menu, page footer, etc.).
  4. `tests.robot` with all tests I will perform in the home page. The *Settings* section invokes the other files (except for **init** which is automatically detected) like this:

> Resource  *Resources.robot*
>
> Resource  *PageObjects.robot*
>
> Resource  *../GeneralResources.robot*

- `/about` folder will also contain 4 files, organized the same way as the /home folder.
- `/products` folder will also contain 4 files, organized the same way as the /home folder.
- `/contactus` folder will also contain 4 files, organized the same way as the /home folder.

I'm not exactly sure this is the right way to go, as 4 files per page seem like quite an overhead. I'd like to know if I'm overlooking something, or if maybe some of the files I'm using should be merged into one.

Comment: Have you considered writing your keywords in python? It gives you a lot more flexibility. I wrote a page object library that makes this really easy. See  https://github.com/boakley/robotframework-pageobjectlibrary. Unfortunately,  answers to this question will be mostly opinions, and that type of question is off topic here.

Comment: Thanks, Bryan. Unfortunately, I have to use Java in my project, and I wasn't able to find any library that will set up the Page Object pattern for me, so I'm trying to organize it myself from scratch. Is my structure not flexible enough?

Answer (score 1):

The Page Object model is a good way of abstracting the application UI from your test logic on a per-page basis.

In the event that your application is structured in separate elements that are reused across several pages then the per-page approach may be less effective.

For an application I work with the ID generation is predictable that the abstraction I chose mirrors the structure of the application and thus per-page I just re-use the basic building blocks that represent the application functionality.